# Declare object of derived class initialising properties of base class

Tags: python, django, django-models

Base class-

```
class Base:
    x = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Derived class-

```
class Derived(Base):
    ...
```

How do I declare an object of Derived class which initialises x like given below without adding constructor in Derived class. This syntax gives the error: x is not a member of Derived.

```
obj = Derived(x='foo')
```

Comment: Is `Base` derived from `models.Model`? You should probably define `Base` with `abstract = True` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are supposed to be Django models, then they should inherit from `Model`:

```
class Base(models.Model):
    x = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Derived(Base):
    pass
```

With that, the call `d = Derived(x='foo')` should work.

---

Note: If you don't want the base class to have its own database table, then you can additionaly use [`abstract = True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) in the Meta class.